# Highlight focused node

Tags: highlight, virtualtreeview

When using getprevious(node) or getnext(node) in VirtualTreeView is it possible to get blue highlight on that previous or next nodes like on select node by click?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you need, whether to highlight the next or previous node without changing actual selected node or simply select different node by code.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you make a node highlighted with blue: *(or other colour set at VST.Colors...)*
`VST.Selected[Node] := True;`

Do not mix with : `VST.FocusedNode` !

You may consider to deselect the previous blue one first.
If `VST.TreeOptions.SelectionOptions >> toMultiSelect = False`, it's enough to simply "remember" the last one:

```
var
  LastSelected: PVirtualNode;  // you can put this to the Form's private section
...  
procedure DeselectLastOne();
begin
  if (csDestroying in VST.ComponentState) then Exit;
  if Assigned(LastSelected) then begin
    VST.Selected[LastSelected] := False;
    LastSelected := nil;
  end;
end;

procedure SelectNewOne(N: PVirtualNode);
begin
  if (csDestroying in VST.ComponentState) then Exit;
  DeselectLastOne();
  VST.Selected[N] := True;
  LastSelected := N;  
end;          

initialization
  LastSelected = nil;  // you can put this to the Form's OnCreate proc.
```

But if you have set `VST.TreeOptions.SelectionOptions >> toMultiSelect = True` than you'll have to iterate through `VST.SelectedNodes()` function first to deselect ALL highlighted nodes.

See also: `VST.SelectedCount : integer;` , `VST.GetFirstSelected()` , `VST.GetNextSelected()`